# How do I add links to these buttons in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to link to other components using react router. I want to add the links to the buttons.

as you can see below in my code that I want to go to another component instead of the google.com links, suppose if I have a ./starter component

Comment: Not sure I understand, but would it help to wrap your button in LINK?
 <Link to={link}>
     <button type="button">
          Click Me!
     </button>
 </Link>

Comment: importing just this would work with the above code? 
import { Route, Link, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to import Link from react-router-dom and instead of using `window.location.href` we  use `<Link to='/path'>`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import SECOND from './data/second';

class Seconds extends Component{
    render(){
        const{title, image, link}=this.props.second;
        return(
            <div style={{display: 'inline-block', width: 300, margin: 10}}>
            *//this is where i want to add the router links to other component, how do I do it??    
<Link to={link}><button><img src={image} alt='profile' style={{width: 90, height: 70, borderRadius: 5}}/><aside>{title}</aside>
                </button></Link>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Now you can wrap your app.js in Router and handle the path using Route tag to load the Component.

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react';
 import First from './First';
 import './App.css';
 import Second from './Second';
 import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
 import MyComponent from '/path';

    class App extends Component{
       render(){      
          return(
             <Router>
              <hr/>
               <First/>
              <hr/>
              <Second/>
              <Route path='/yourpath' component={MyComponent} />
             </Router>
          )
      }
    }
    export default App;
```

Hope it helps!!! :)

Comment: should i also change the links in SECONDS.js file? my second file above

Comment: i did as you said and also the link to the SECONDS.js file but when i click the link, im not being redirected and the url in the address bar becomes "http://localhost:3000/components/course"

Comment: @helloTerminal Can you share your code in codepen or jsbin?

Comment: yeah it's working now, it's atleast opening now. but i want to go to another page like hiding the <First/> and <Second/> files. its a restaurant menu app so that when i click on starter, it shows the dishes of starter course.

Comment: I did. btw can you please tell me how to open it in a new page too?

Comment: @helloTerminal you can use <Link to="/yourpath" target="_blank"> to open the link in new tab.

Comment: it does open but today's special and and courses are still showing

Comment: it's showing like this https://imgur.com/NgRtGMQ i don't want today's' special and courses to show in the new page